# What values do type from EVP_CipherInit_ex return?

Tags: c, openssl, aes

```
EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, NULL, NULL, do_encrypt);
```

In the above code, **EVP_CipherInit_ex** calls EVP_aes_128_cbc or it could call other **const EVP_CIPHER *type**. Is there a constant value that it returns?

I tried looking for documentation or codes, but couldn't find any information on what **const EVP_CIPHER *type** returns.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you're looking for, but I tried googling for "typedef EVP_CIPHER" to see what could be found about that type.

From this page: https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/openssl/1.0.1c/crypto_2ossl__typ_8h.html#a54a8663a8084d45c31f2786156b55405:

`typedef struct evp_cipher_st   EVP_CIPHER`

Looks like `EVP_CIPHER` is a typedef for `struct evp_cipher_st` which is seemingly what the function call returns in `EVP_aes_128_cbc()`